# Image Curve from Square Mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem**: For $z \in \mathbb{R}$, let $l_z$ denote an arbitrary line in $\mathbb{C}$ through the point $z$ and put $f(z) = z^2$. For $z=2$ show that, regardless of the slope of $l_2$, the angle between the lines $l_2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is the same as the angle of the tangent lines of the image curves $f(l_2) = \{z^2 \in \mathbb{C}; z \in l_2\}$ and $f(\mathbb{R})$ at the image point $f(2) =4$.

My primary issue is determining the equation for the image curve so that I can find the equation for the tangent lines. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $l_z = 2+te^{i\theta}$ where $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\theta$ is the angle of $l_z$ and the $x$-axis

We have: $$f(l_z) = (2+te^{i\theta})^2 = 4 + 4te^{i\theta} + t^2e^{2i\theta} = 4+4t\cos \theta+t^2\cos 2\theta + i(4t\sin\theta+t^2\sin 2\theta)$$

You need to show that the angle between the tangent to $f(l_z)$ at $t=0$ and the $x$-axis is $\theta$